# Magento - plugin overwrite local.xml block

Tags: magento

I have a local.xml file that has the following:

```
<default>
   <cms_index_index translate="label">
      <reference name="masthead">
          <block type="page/html" template="cms/masthead/homepage.phtml" as="banners" />
      </reference>
   </cms_index_index translate="label">
</default>
```

I have a plugin that has it's own config.xml - I wish to override the above block with a template located in: /app/code/local/MageWorx/GeoIP/cms/homepage.phtml.

The config.xml file is however different and looks like:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MageWorx_GeoIP>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </MageWorx_GeoIP>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <MageWorx_GeoIP>
                <files>
                    <default>MageWorx_GeoIP.csv</default>
                </files>
            </MageWorx_GeoIP>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <routers>
        <geoip>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MageWorx_GeoIP</module>
                <frontName>geoip</frontName>
            </args>
        </geoip>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <geoip>
                <file>geoip.xml</file>
            </geoip>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <geoip>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>geoipAutoswitcher</method>
                </geoip>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <controller_action_predispatch_directory_currency_switch>
            <observers>
                <geoip>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setCurrency</method>
                </geoip>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_directory_currency_switch> 
    </events>
</frontend>

<global>
    <models>
        <geoip>
            <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>geoip_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </geoip>
        <geoip_mysql4>
            <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Model_Mysql4</class>
        </geoip_mysql4>
        <core>
            <rewrite>
                <store>MageWorx_GeoIP_Model_Core_Store</store>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <geoip_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>MageWorx_GeoIP</module>
                <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </geoip_setup>
        <geoip_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </geoip_write>
        <geoip_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </geoip_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <geoip>
            <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Block</class>
        </geoip>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view_info>MageWorx_Adminhtml_Block_Geoip_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
                <customer_online_grid>MageWorx_Adminhtml_Block_Geoip_Adminhtml_Customer_Online_Grid</customer_online_grid>
                <system_store_edit_form>MageWorx_Adminhtml_Block_Geoip_Adminhtml_System_Store_Edit_Form</system_store_edit_form>
            </rewrite> 
        </adminhtml>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_billing>MageWorx_GeoIP_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Billing</onepage_billing>
                <onepage_shipping>MageWorx_GeoIP_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping</onepage_shipping>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
        <customer>
            <rewrite>
                <address_edit>MageWorx_GeoIP_Block_Customer_Address_Edit</address_edit>
            </rewrite>
        </customer>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <geoip>
            <class>MageWorx_GeoIP_Helper</class>
        </geoip>
    </helpers>
</global>

<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all><title>Allow Everything</title></all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <mageworx_customers translate="title" module="mageworx">
                                    <title>MageWorx &gt; Customers</title>
                                    <sort_order>1</sort_order> 
                                        <children>
                                            <geoip translate="title" module="geoip">
                                                <title>GeoIP Location</title>
                                            </geoip>
                                        </children>
                                    </mageworx_customers>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <geoip>
                <file>geoip.xml</file>
            </geoip>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<default>
    <mageworx_customers>
        <geoip>
            <enable_store_switcher>1</enable_store_switcher>
            <enable_currency_switcher>1</enable_currency_switcher>
            <force_store_view>1</force_store_view>
            <store_switcher_scope>1</store_switcher_scope>
            <disable_store_switcher_key>off</disable_store_switcher_key>
            <store_switcher_exception_urls>/paypal/*</store_switcher_exception_urls>
            <db_type>1</db_type>
            <db_path>lib/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat</db_path>
            <enable_billing_country>1</enable_billing_country>
            <enable_shipping_country>1</enable_shipping_country>
            <enable_address_country>1</enable_address_country>
        </geoip>
    </mageworx_customers>
</default>
```

Does anyone know where and what I should add in that config.xml to override the local.xml block?

Comment: Local.xml is always loaded last, see `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::getFileLayoutUpdatesXml`. It's not intended to load layout updates after it.  Why can't you modify your local.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not override any of your block or action with local.xml to config.xml

here is magento truth is

config.xml and local.xml are loaded together, along with any other xml file you place in app/local. They are loaded in `Mage_Core_Model_Config::loadBase()`

```
public function loadBase()
    {
        $etcDir = $this->getOptions()->getEtcDir();
        $files = glob($etcDir.DS.'*.xml');
        $this->loadFile(current($files));
        while ($file = next($files)) {
            $merge = clone $this->_prototype;
            $merge->loadFile($file);
            $this->extend($merge);
        }
        if (in_array($etcDir.DS.'local.xml', $files)) {
            $this->_isLocalConfigLoaded = true;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

And if your want to understand more about [local.xml](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/), see this.

hope you can understand more clearly now.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining. I'm still a bit confused as the <rewrite>           <onepage_billing>MageWorx_GeoIP_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Billing</onepage_billing> line is pulling in a different address block than, but i'm guessing that isn't in local.xml in the first place

Comment: Can I do the same (rewrite) for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you know what I need to add in to get it to rewrite it?

Comment: yes i am guessing you want to rewrite onepage billing action with your custom logic.or any thing else pls let me know

Comment: I need to rewrite cms/masthead/homepage.phtml to /app/code/local/MageWorx/GeoIP/cms/homepage.phtml so the 2nd template is used. Is that possible?

Comment: you can follow this link http://magento4u.wordpress.com/category/class-override/block-override/ and also refer http://magento4u.wordpress.com/category/class-override/block-override/ sure help you